# creating a database table for week schedule

Tags: python, django

I want to create a model for storing a weekly schedule for a doctor, my approach is currently like this:

```
class ScheduleDay(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    #the name of the week day
    day = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    clinic = models.ForeignKey(Clinic, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

Is that a good design?

Comment: This is a good way to design a model , Django's documentation can also guide you through the different ways to design your models: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/

Comment: Instead of `day` + `start/end_time` I'd define `datetime_start` and `datetime_end` as `DatetimeField()`, so you can filter the data by time easier when eventually needed.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko  the day is for storing the name of the day of  the week not the date

Comment: You can always get name of day from `DatetimeField`, but you cant get date from a name of the day. It's more futureproof this way, you never know what requirement will come next.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko
i know, but i don't want to update the datetimefield each week, if you have a better option, please tell me

Comment: the question is specified very vaguely, so I cant tell what is the exact use-case. In such case go ahead then.